# Implement Menubar at bottom like Tabbar using addChildViewController in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uiviewcontroller

i am working with the application which have Custom menu at bottom of the screen (Like Tabbar).Custom Menu will be display in all `UIViewController`.

Ex : i have 6 menu button at bottom. When i click on `Button1` i can see the  `UIViewController1` at above of the Custom Menu. `UIViewController1`have `UITableView` and list will be display. When i click on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` `UIViewController2` will be open with navigation.

How to achieve this using `addChildViewController`. ?

i had refer [this link](https://github.com/toolmanGitHub/stackedViewControllers) but not getting the success with my different `UIViewController` to with push.

Answer (score 0):

```
It is very simple u can do it in multiple ways one way is to add navigation controller to root view controller and then push all the views one by one according to requirement.

Your you can addview also like this

 SecondView * myModalVC = [[SecondView alloc] init];
/*
    [myModalVC setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    [self presentViewController:myModalVC animated:YES completion:NULL];

 */

/*
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:3.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp animations:^{[self.view addSubview:myModalVC.view];} completion:NULL];


    */
    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 1.25;
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight; //choose your animation
    [transition setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault]];

    [myModalVC.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];


      [self presentViewController:myModalVC animated:NO completion:NULL];

   // [self transitionFromViewController:self toViewController:myModalVC duration:2.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations:<#^(void)animations#> completion:<#^(BOOL finished)completion#>]
```

which ever u like u can simple use  :)